# ordenamiento de un fichero txt

Tags: java

Tengo un txt que para tener una mejor visualizacion de este es preferible hacer un ordenamiento.

Para hacer esta informacion mas entendible esta dividida por "pipes"( | ) y como te puedes dar cuenta cada 001 es un nuevo registro entonces todo ese registro hasta que encuentra nuevamente un 001 sera de esa persona.

```
001|nombre completo|numero identificador|datos necesarios
002|descripcion de la persona|datos necesarios
002|mas descripcion de la persona|datos necesarios
005|resultados de la persona| datos necesarios
001|nombre completo|numero identificador|datos necesarios
003|descripcion de la persona|datos necesarios
004|mas descripcion de la persona|datos necesarios
005|resultados de la persona| datos necesarios
001|nombre completo|numero identificador|datos necesarios
002|descripcion de la persona|datos necesarios
003|mas descripcion de la persona|datos necesarios
004|resultados de la persona| datos necesarios
```

El archivo viene de la siguiente manera

```
001|Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|primeros datos necesarios
002|descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
002|mas descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
005|resultados de la persona primero| datos necesarios
001|Humberto Espindola N.|JAJJ010101JJJ|datos necesarios
003|descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
004|mas descripcion de la persona|datos necesarios
005|resultados de la persona primero| datos necesarios
001|Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|segundos datos necesarios
002|descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
003|mas descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
004|resultados de la persona segundo| datos necesarios
```

Para tener un nuevo identificador de cada registro nuevo quiero agregarle un 000 y colocar la informacion de acuerdo a "numero identificador" y de la siguiente manera

```
000
001|Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|primeros datos necesarios
001|Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|segundos datos necesarios
002|descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
002|mas descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
002|descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
003|mas descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
004|resultados de la persona segundo| datos necesarios
005|resultados de la persona primero| datos necesarios
000
001|Humberto Espindola N.|JAJJ010101JJJ|datos necesarios
003|descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
004|mas descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
005|resultados de la persona primero| datos necesarios
```

EL problema con el que me enfrento es el como puedo obtener la informacion de todo ese registro, ya tengo localizada la variable, tengo la idea de la comparacion para comparar con otro "numero identificador" pero no logro obtener la informacion de ese registro, separarlo y añadirle lo de un nuevo registro cuando "numero identificador" es igual e imprimirlo en el fichero nuevo, necesito hacer nuevamente una lectura? o leo las demas lineas apartir de ese punto, o que otras ideas no tengo contempladas para poder solucionar esta clase de ordenamiento?

```
public static String obtenerSeccion(String registro) {
    if (registro.split("\\|").length > 1) {
        return registro.split("\\|")[0];
    }
    return null;
}


public static String obtenerCodigoCliente(String registro) {
    if( registro.split("|").length > 1 ) {
        return registro.split("\\|")[1];
    }
    return null;
}

private static void escribirLinea(String registro) {

    try (
            FileWriter archivo_escrito = new FileWriter("C:/1nuevo.txt",true);
            PrintWriter escritor = new PrintWriter(archivo_escrito);
        ) {

        //Se imprime en archivo el registro completo
        //escritor.println(registro);
        System.out.println(registro);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}

public static void agregarRegistrosPorTipo(String tipoProducto, String registro)  {

    if (tipoProducto == null) {
        return;
    }

    escribirLinea(registro);
}


public static void main(String args[]) {

    String linea = "";
    String codigo_cliente;
    String seccion = "";
    String nuevo_codigo_cliente;

    try ( FileReader archivo_lectura = new FileReader("C:/1.txt"); 
            BufferedReader buffer_lectura = new BufferedReader(archivo_lectura) ){

        while( ( linea = buffer_lectura.readLine() ) != null) {

            //Obtenermos seccion del bloque
            seccion = obtenerSeccion(linea);
            codigo_cliente = "";

            //Se obtiene el tipo de producto
            if( seccion != null && seccion.equals("001") ) {

                codigo_cliente = obtenerCodigoCliente(linea);

            }
            agregarRegistrosPorTipo(codigo_cliente,linea);
        }
        buffer_lectura.close();
    }catch(IOException e){

        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es el código que estas tratando?

Comment: acabo de actualizar el  post

Comment: estoy trabajado en eso, solo que es complicado enterder que es lo que quieres, segun veo esa estructura de dastos no tiene nigun sentido.. intenta explicar un poco mas.

Answer (score 0):

Vaya, quiero decirte que fue algo costoso hacerte este codigo, agrege el lector del identificador, despues del **001|** va el identificador: **|001|**, esto se veria asi:

```
000
001|001|Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|primeros datos necesarios
002|002|Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|segundos datos necesarios
003|001|descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
004|001|mas descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios
005|002|descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
006|002|mas descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
007|002|resultados de la persona segundo| datos necesarios
008|001|resultados de la persona primero| datos necesarios
000
001|Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|segundos datos necesarios
002|descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
003|mas descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios
004|resultados de la persona segundo| datos necesarios
```

El codigo lo que hace es poder leer y escribir un nuevo registro con o sin identificador como los de arriba...
Es facil de manejar, te dejo dos ejemplo(como escribir y como leer) segun esa estracura...
nota: no ocupes linea en blacon(`"\n"`) puede que tengas errores a la hora de leerlo..

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
//@Test
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final boolean testWrite = true;
    final boolean testRead = true;

    final File fout = new File("C:\\Users\\christian\\Documents\\cjavier_projects\\out.txt");

    if(!fout.exists()) {
        try {
            fout.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    final FileRegistroManager manager = new FileRegistroManager(fout);

    try {
        if(testWrite) {
            writeTest(manager,System.out);
        }
        System.out.println();
        if(testRead) {
            readTest(manager, System.out);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print("fin*****************************************");
}

private static void readTest(final FileRegistroManager manager, final PrintStream out) throws FileNotFoundException {
    out.println("begin test read");
    manager.load();
    List<Registro> registros = manager.copyRegistros();

    final Registro registro1 = registros.get(0);
    final Registro registro2 = registros.get(1);

    final LinkedList<Registro> subRegistros = new LinkedList(FileRegistroManager.readTree(registro1));

    for(final Registro registro: subRegistros) {
        out.println("id: " + registro.getId());
        final List<String> lines = registro.copyLines();

        for(String line: lines) {
            out.println(line);
        }
    }

    out.println();
    {
        final List<String> lines = registro2.copyLines();
        for(String line: lines) {
            out.println(line);
        }
    }

    out.println("end test read");
}

private static void writeTest(final FileRegistroManager manager, final PrintStream out) throws FileNotFoundException {
    out.println("begin test write");
    final LinkedList<Registro> registros = new LinkedList();
    final LinkedList<Registro> list = new LinkedList();

    writeTest(registros);

    Registro registro;

    registro = FileRegistroManager.writeTree(registros);
    list.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro();
    registro.addLine("Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|segundos datos necesarios");
    registro.addLine("descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios");
    registro.addLine("mas descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios");
    registro.addLine("resultados de la persona segundo| datos necesarios");
    //registro.addLine("");
    list.add(registro);

    manager.writeRegistros(list);
    out.println("end test write");
}

private static void writeTest(final LinkedList<Registro> registros) {

    Registro registro;


    registro = new Registro(1);
    registro.addLine("Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|primeros datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro(2);
    registro.addLine("Fabricio Hdez. G.|XAXX010101XXX|segundos datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro(1);
    registro.addLine("descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro(1);
    registro.addLine("mas descripcion de la persona primero|datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro(2);
    registro.addLine("descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro(2);
    registro.addLine("mas descripcion de la persona segundo|datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro(2);
    registro.addLine("resultados de la persona segundo| datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    registro = new Registro(1);
    registro.addLine("resultados de la persona primero| datos necesarios");
    registros.add(registro);

    //registro = new Registro(id);
    //registro.addLine(line);
    //registros.add(registro);
}

public static class FileRegistroManager {

    private static final String startRegistro = "000";

    private LinkedList<Registro> registros;

    private File file;

    public static Collection<Registro> readTree(final Registro registro) {

        final LinkedHashMap<Short, Registro> registros = new LinkedHashMap();

        final List<String> lines = registro.copyLines();
        for(final String line_: lines) {
            short id = new Short(line_.substring(0,3));
            final String line = line_.substring(4);

            if (!registros.containsKey(id)) {
                registros.put(id, new Registro(id));
            }
            registros.get(id).addLine(line);
        }

        final ArrayList<Registro> list = new ArrayList(registros.size());
        final Set<Short> keys = registros.keySet();

        for(Short key:keys) {
            list.add(registros.get(key));
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void writeRegistros(final Registro[] registros) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final LinkedList<Registro> list = new LinkedList();

        for(Registro registro: registros) {
            list.add(registro);
        }

        writeRegistros(list);
    }

    public static Registro writeTree(final Collection<Registro> registros) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final PrintStream psm = new PrintStream(out, false);

        for(Registro registro: registros) {
            String pre = "";
            if(registro.getId() < 10) {
                pre += "00" + registro.getId();
            }else if(registro.getId() < 100) {
                pre += "0" + registro.getId();
            }else {
                pre += registro.getId();
            }
            pre += '|';
            final Collection<String> list = registro.copyLines();
            for(String line: list) {
                psm.println(pre + line);
            }
        }

        psm.flush();
        psm.close();

        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
        final LinkedList<String> lines = new LinkedList();
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();
        return new Registro(lines);

    }

    public FileRegistroManager(final File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public FileRegistroManager(final String filePath) {
        this(new File(filePath));
    }

    public void load() throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.registros = new LinkedList();
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

        Registro registro = null;

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();

            if(line.startsWith(startRegistro)) {
                registro = new Registro();
                if(registro != null)
                    registros.add(registro);
                continue;
            }

            registro.addLine(line.substring(4)/* ignore: 001| */);
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    public List<Registro> copyRegistros() {
        return new ArrayList(this.registros);
    }

    public void writeRegistros(Collection<Registro> registros) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final PrintStream psm = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file), false);

        for(Registro registro: registros ) {
            short line = 1;
            psm.println(startRegistro);
            for(String txtLine: registro.lines) {

                txtLine = '|' + txtLine;

                if(line < 10) {
                    txtLine = "00" + line + txtLine;
                }else if(line < 100) {
                    txtLine = "0" + line + txtLine;
                }else {
                    txtLine = line + txtLine;
                }
                line++;

                psm.println(txtLine);
            }
        }
        psm.flush();
        psm.close();
    }

}

public static class Registro {

    private LinkedList<String> lines;

    private short id = 1;

    public Registro() {
        this(0);
    }

    public Registro(Registro copyFrom) {
        this(copyFrom.lines);
    }

    public Registro(Collection<String> lines) {
        this.lines = new LinkedList(lines);
    }

    public Registro(short id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lines = new LinkedList();
    }

    public Registro(int id) {
        this((short)id);
    }

    public List<String> copyLines() {
        return new ArrayList(lines);
    }

    public void setLines(final Collection<String> lines) {
        this.lines = new LinkedList(lines);
    }

    public void addLine(String line) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    public short getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str;
        str = "id: " + id ;
        return str;
    }
}
```

nota: lo comento mas tarde, ahorita estoy cansado.